# combine two data frame based on cell value in R

Tags: r, merge

I have two data frames. One is the baseline data for different test type and the other one is my experiment data. Now I would like to combine this two data frame together. But it is not a simply merge or rbind. I wonder any R professionals can help me to solve it. Thank you.

Here is a example of two data frames:

```
experiment data:
experiment_num   timepoint     type     value
50                   10       7a,b4       90
50                   20       7a,b4       89
50                   20       10a,b4      93
50                   10       7a,b6       85
50                   20       7a,b6       87
50                   20       10a,b6      88 

baseline data:
experiment_num   timepoint      type    value
50                    0         0,b4      85
50                    0         0,b6      90
```

Here is the output I would like to have:

```
experiment_num    timepoint     type    value
50                    0         7a,b4     85
50                    10        7a,b4     90
50                    20        7a,b4     89
50                    0         10a,b4    85
50                    20        10a,b4    89
50                    0         7a,b6     90
50                    10        7a,b6     85
50                    20        7a,b6     87
50                    0         10a,b6    90
50                    20        10a,b6    88
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on the join. I see that for each type of the `experiment data` you take `baseline data` where `value` is baseline data `85` or `90`. what is the rational there?

Comment: I figured it out. It depends on the second part of the `type`

Comment: @dimitris_ps, the type of type column is "character"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job. You first need to install a couple of packages:

```
install.packages("dplyr")
install.packages("tidyr")
```

*** Data ***

```
ed <- data.frame(experiment_num=rep(50, 6), timepoint=rep(c(10, 20, 20), 2), 
             type=c("7a,b4", "7a,b4", "10a,b4", "7a,b6", "7a,b6", "10a,b6"),
             value=c(90, 89, 93, 85, 87, 88))


db <- data.frame(experiment_num=rep(50, 2), timepoint=rep(0, 2), type=c("0,b4", "0,b6"),
             value=c(85, 90))
```

*** Code ***

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

final <- rbind(separate(ed, type, into=c("typea", "typeb")), 
           left_join(ed %>% select(type) %>% unique %>% 
           separate(type, into=c("typea", "typeb")),
           separate(db, type, into=c("zero", "typeb"))) %>% 
    select(experiment_num, timepoint, typea, typeb, value)
  ) %>% 
  arrange(typeb, typea, timepoint) %>% mutate(type=paste(typea, typeb, sep=",")) %>% 
  select(experiment_num, timepoint, type, value)
```

The logic is the following.
Separate the `type` into two columns `typea` and `typeb` then "create" the missing `typea` for baseline data. and then join to the experimental data.

`final` is the data set you are looking for.

Comment: I am really new to these two packages. Could you explain how "%>%" works here? I want to learn. Thank you

Comment: Please note that `%>%` originally comes from the `magrittr` package, but is also included in `dplyr` - their help pages and online documentation explain it better than I could (short explanation though: `a%f()` means use `a` as the first argument in `f()` (i.e. `f(a)`) - that's all really, it just makes reading code easier for some people.)

Comment: @maj thank you so much. I will take a look at the help in that package

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write `a %>% f()`, not `a % f()`.